# Margin from the second line

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to margin a text from the second line. I just know text spacing & margin but it doesn't help in thie case. How to do like the picture below.

[image]

Comment: check to this i think u want this http://tinkerbin.com/OpC9x2YU

Comment: Sorry, I uploaded the pic but it doesn't show here.

Comment: Provide your HTML source code & css. Show what you have tried so far

Comment: I set margin for each number entry above but it margins whole div. I want to margin from the second line of a paragraph.

Comment: @Emerald214 can u provide your html and css code

Comment: please provide the code @Emerald214

Comment: Sorry I can't. The code belongs to my company. :)
 BTW You make me laugh out loud. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this may helpful to you..

```
 <dl>
 <dt>1. Coffee</dt>
 <dd>black hot drink</dd>
 <dt>2.Milk</dt>
 <dd>white cold drink</dd>
 </dl>
```

**Demo**: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/22w48/)

otherwise use this

```
<ol>
<li></p>Something here...</p></p>Something more here...</p></p>Something something something</p> </li>
<li></p>Something else...</p></p>Something else here...</p></p>Something something something</p> </li>
</ol>
```

1. Something here...Something more here...Something something something
2. Something else...Something else here...Something something something

Answer (score 2):

You can use the built-in numbered list in HTML. i.e. the `<ol>` tag:

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/x9v2t/

**Code**:

```
<ol>
    <li>Hello World. This is a line in this paragraph that can span mulitple lines. Hello World. This is a line in this paragraph that can span mulitple lines.</li>
    <li>Hello World. This is a line in this paragraph that can span mulitple lines. Hello World. This is a line in this paragraph that can span mulitple lines.</li>
    <li>Hello World. This is a line in this paragraph that can span mulitple lines. Hello World. This is a line in this paragraph that can span mulitple lines.</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: What if the second line need margin a little bit more? I mean it doesn't align to the first line.

Comment: That may be difficult with ol. But this can work if what you need is as per the image attached in the question.

Answer (score 1):

---

Hi now used to this

```
 p+p{
  margin-top:10px;}
```

***[Live demo](http://tinkerbin.com/2h8tCmRa)***